# How to convert hash with keys representing nesting into a nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I need to convert the following hash:

```
{
  "item[0][size]" => "12",
  "item[0][count]" => "1"
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "item": {
    "0": {
      "size": "12",
      "count": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please advice on how to achieve that most gracefully? Maybe I can reuse some ActionPack's utility method that is used for parsing parameter strings?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: tried searching the actionpack's codebase and tried `CGI::parse('item[0][size]=12')` but it doesn't parse the nested key string

Comment: What is the source of that hash? It might make sense to fix it there instead of building a workaround.

Comment: @spickermann the source of the hash is a CSV file. In order to represent nested objects values, I have to use some convention and I though about using the same way as for nested parameter keys.

Comment: @Зелёный You didn't need to delete your answer. It was good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a way to parse nested query keys using http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Utils/parse_nested_query:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query('item[0][size]')
=> {
  "item" => {
    "0" => {
      "size" => nil
    }
  }
}
```

So it's now possible to do:

```
items_string = item_hash.to_a.map { |row| row.join('=') }.join('&')
result = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(items_string)

=> {
  "item" => {
    "0" => {
       "size" => "12",
      "count" => "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not give what you asked for. Be consistent.

Comment: @sawa, updated the expected result to have strings as values. But I was looking for an idea to convert nested key into hash, which I've found. Regards

Comment: Not only the values but also the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse a `rack` lib method [`Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb)

```
require "rack"
def p p
  Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(p)                                               
end
p 'item[0][size]=12' # => {"item"=>{"0"=>{"size"=>"12"}}}
```

Found [here](http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query).

Comment: Note that this is close but not the same as what the OP asked for.

Comment: @sawa yep, but my answer based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738395/how-to-convert-hash-with-keys-representing-nesting-into-a-nested-hash/33739000?noredirect=1#comment55245796_33738395) OP comment. And yes it's unclear what OP asked.